# Getting errors in activity when upgrading dependencies implementations versions in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

When I upgrade any implementation I get errors in my imports in the activity.
I'm using Intellij IDEA 2023.3.2 and I have these gradle dependencies implementations

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

And this is the other gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: The imports getting errors like import androidx.compose.material3.* I get error for material3

Answer (score 0):

Use Compose BOM to maintain compatibility among the compose dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'

    // Android Studio Preview support
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

Full guide is available [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#groovy_1).

Comment: Didn't work and I followed the full guide